# How to modify the font family within bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I'm currently trying to change the default font family that is set within bootstrap. As my current CSS code is being overwritten by: scaffolding.less.

[image]

[image]

The first output as seen above shows the text being overwritten by scaffolding.less.

[image]

[image]

The test above shows the correct text font after removeing the css line within the chrome dev tools.

I would like to know How would this be implemented within CSS?

Current Code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" type="text/css">
    <style>
html {
    font: normal 400 1em/1 'Open Sans', Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go in your boostrap file bootstrap.min.css find font-family and put the one you want..